# Final render is empty when a specific object is shown (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, visibility

I'm using IvyGen with an array modifier. The final render shows no objects when the collection with all the Ivys is enabled in the final render, but is completely fine when enabled in viewport or disabled in final render.
[image: Here is the render with the Ivys enabled]

[image: Here is the render with the Ivys disabled]

[image: Viewport]

Everything else is the exact same, only the camera icon is disabled in the outliner.
scene has 13.1M verts (decimate modifier enabled in viewport, disabled in render)

Laptop has 4GB physical RAM with 12GB of SSD space used for virtual memory. Ryzen 3 3250u, CPU rendering. Blender version: 3.6.0
[image: Render Performance Settings]

[image: Main Render Settings]

Comment: In the Outliner you have some objects that are disabled for render, is it normal?